# Loop through a table in crystal-reports

Tags: crystal-reports, crystal-reports-xi

I have 2 linked tables to report on: 
- 1st keeps solutions and links to the 2nd. The important fields are solution, type, typeID
- 2nd holds information about categories. The fields to be used are typeID, type, parentTypeID, treeLvl. The parentTypeID refers to the typeID of a higher level in structure.

I need to get the solution and the type to recreate the whole tree structure. Currently I have the second table linked 5 times to itself using Left Outer Join, but want to do it in the loop.

I'm thinking about something along these lines, but need it to work:

```
numberVar level := {KBTYPES.TREELVL};
stringVar currentType;
numberVar type;
while level >= 1 do 
(
currentType := {KBTYPES.TYPE} & currentType;
type := {KBTYPES.ParentKBTypeId};
{KBTYPES.KB_TYPEID} := type;
level -1;
);
currentType
```

Comment: can you clarify- are you hoping to get rid of the 5 aliases of the table?

Comment: yes, I'd like to have only 1 alias from the Solutions table to the Types table, and then loop throught the Types to get the full tree structure.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm fairly confident in saying what you want to do is not possible. Do the types change or is that table fairly static? Are there a lot of values? You could consider actually bringing the key/value pairs into your looping function.

What is your datasource? You will probably stand a much better chance of achieving this at the source (with a sproc/function/view)

I've not tested it but this is the first result from google using a common table expression: http://mycodingexperience.blogspot.co.uk/2011/04/common-table-expression-cte-and-tree.html

Comment: There is not a lot of data in there, around 140 records in the types table. The whole database is pretty much static, there is not much going on there, I guess I'll just sort it all manually in the spreadsheet.  I'm new to crystal reports, and don't have much experience in coding as well, I'm trying to find out what can be done with this.  I thought it would be possible to take the value from one field (parenttypeID), save it to the variable, then use that value to find another record in the table (by assigning it to the typeID). Do you think such a thing is not possible there?

Comment: No, you can't seek to different records in that way (you have to link the tables in the database expert. I hate the idea of hardcoding the function in Crystal even if it is fairly static. You didn't answer the question re: Datasource? A fairly simple common table expression (CTE) can be used to achieve this at the source if memory serves me correctly.

Comment: The source is MS SQL 2005.  It looks like CTE can do just what I want, but how do you use it within Crystal Report?  Will something like the code below work:      
    WITH TypeTreeCTE (TypeID, Type, ParentId, Level) As
(
SELECT KB_TypeID, Type, ParentId, TreeLvl From KBTypes
UNION
SELECT TypeTreeCTE.TypeID, TypeTreeCTE.Type, TypeTreeCTE.ParentId, TypeTreeCTE.Level From TypeTreeCTE WHERE 
TypeTreeCTE.ParentId <> -1 AND TypeTreeCTE.TypeId = TypeTreeCTE.ParentId 
) 
SELECT TypeTreeCTE.Type From TypeTreeCTE WHERE TypeTreeCTE.KB_TypeID = Solutions.KB_TypeID

Comment: I would probably create a view using the CTE then point the Crystal Report at the view. You will need to run the CTE in SQL Server Management Studio or Query Analyser or similar to check the output is what you need. If you're struggling I would ask another question specifically for help with the CTE.

Comment: Thanks a lot, I'll play with this.